# ¿Insertar datos en bd desde web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

estoy teniendo un par de problemas con un API en ASP.Net, trato de guardar datos de esta manera:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostExpediente([FromBody] ExpedienteDto expedientePOCO)
    {
        Ejercicio2Entities context = new Ejercicio2Entities();
        using (context)
        {
            Expediente expediente = new Expediente();
                expediente.idExpediente = expedientePOCO.idExpediente;
                expediente.NombreExpediente = expedientePOCO.NombreExpediente;
                expediente.FechaCreacion = expedientePOCO.FechaCreacion;
                expediente.DuenioExpediente = expedientePOCO.DuenioExpediente;

            expediente.CantidadDocumento = expedientePOCO.Documentos.Count;
            if (expediente.Documento.Count == 0)
                db.Expediente.Add(expediente);
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Database.Log = msg => Trace.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

El parametro lo paso de esta manera a travéz de POSTMAN:

```
{
    "idExpediente": 0,
    "NombreExpediente": "Expediente A",
    "FechaCreacion": "2018-01-19T09:25:25.717",
    "DuenioExpediente": "Alex",
    "CantidadDocumento": 0
 }
```

El api recibe exitosamente el parametro, se asigna correctamente a la entidad de EF, pasa exitosamente al ObjectContext.SaveChanges() pero no hace el guardado. No da error ni nada, simplemente no funciona. Alguna idea?

Comment: Creo que debrias poner "context.Expediente.Add(expediente)"; en vez de "db.Expediente.Add(expediente)"

Comment: Saludos hermano, por curiosidad, ¿De dónde salió "bd"?

Comment: Tenes toda la razón del mundo, gracias. No me había fijado en ese pequeño, gran detalle jejeje